# Selenium - How to find an object without it having and Id or a Name?

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have recently started using Selenium Webdriver for automation. The webpage I'm trying to automate is in CSS. So what I'm try to achieve is click on a dropdown "Admin", which will then show a list. And select one of the options "User Access" from that list.

Now in the page source, this particular dropdown "Admin" does not have an ID or a Name. Below is the code for reference:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        Admin<span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

        <li>
            <a href="usersAdmin">
                Users Admin
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="userAccess">
                User Access Admin
            </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="#">
                Email Object Admin
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</li>
```

Now I want to select the User Access Admin value from the dropdown? I'm trying to use the findElement method to identify that object, but since it doesn't have an ID or a name, I'm not able to do that successfully. What would be a suitable method to do this?
I'm using Java for coding.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

**Java**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Users Admin"));
```

**C#**

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("Users Admin"));
```

**Python**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Users Admin")
```

Comment: Thank you. But this is not working. That is because, 'Admin' is a label, and clicking on that label, will enable the dropdown. I think we need to get 'Admin' to be clicked first, before we can select the 'Users Admin' value.

Comment: @RahulBaskaran Use the same code to Click on Admin first and then Users Admin, Just change the string.

Answer (score 1):

Should the following css be sufficient?

```
a[href='userAccess']
```

Comment: I think you may omit the quotes: `a[href=userAccess]`

Answer (score 1):

In your case if you want to open the dropdown and choose the "Users Admin" option, then try the following:

```
// find the dropdown and open it
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Admin")).click();

// find the interesting element and select it via a click
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Users Admin")).click();
```